# SendSMS example sketch hangs at PINMUNBER if statement

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I'm using an Arduino shield connected to an Arduino Uno for sending text messages. I'm using one of the in built examples from the Arduino IDE for sending SMS by name - `sendsms` in the GSM examples. However, the code doesnt work at all... it keeps hanging at the line

```
if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY)
```

and never goes beyond it.

I didn't keep any pincode for my SIM card. please help

[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: Post your code properly. Does the shield show any sign that it is on, like a blinking LED? Do you have a SIM attached?

Comment: ...and please summarize your problem in the title. Success.

Comment: You can't just straight away to send SMS, you need to send commands to establish the Serial communication with the module, register to the network, and if the module acknowledged that it has register to the network, you can then start sending msg. Whatever library you are using, it should come with the examples, try those and try to understand the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sketch:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial gsm(2,3);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gsm.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (gsm.available() > 0)
    Serial.write(gsm.read());
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
    gsm.write(Serial.read());
}
```

This sketch will help troubleshoot exactly what's wrong with your setup, without the clutter of a library.

Connect the shield's TX pin to Arduino pin 2 and the shield's RX pin to Arduino pin 3. Ensure that all GNDs are connected. Upload the sketch. Set your serial monitor to `BOTH NL & CR` and the baud rate to 9600. Enter `AT` from the serial monitor. If you recieve `OK`, it means comms have been established with the shield. If you receive gibberish, change the SoftwareSerial baud rate to values from 19200, 57600, etc. until you get a legible response.

Then send the command `AT+CREG?` to check the SIM's registration status. If you get something like `+CREG: *, 1` or `+CREG: *, 5` (* means 'dont care'), then your SIM has been registered on the network. Report your results here.